# Insert a JQuery click handler that executes before the ones already registered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach a click event handler to each and every (Button, Anchor, Select) on all pages  in my application, and that handler should run before the already attached handlers declared in html like `onclick="return SomeFunction('a','b');"`.

I found a question on stackoverflow for prepending handlers, and that was what I wanted exactly, the link to the question is:-

[Jquery prepend click handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264954/jquery-prepend-click-handler)

But, the above code is not working, I doubt if it worked for the asker or not. The code I have written according to my requirements is:-

```
<input type="button" value="Click 1" onclick="f2();" />

$(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[type=button]").each(function() {

                // your button
                var btn = $(this);

                // original click handler
                var clickhandler = btn.attr("onclick");
                btn.attr("onclick", "return false;");


                // new click handler
                btn.click(function() {
                    alert('Prepended Handler');
                    clickhandler();
                });
            });
        });

        function f2() {
            alert('Handler declared in HTML');
        }
```

The output for this code should have been: An alert showing "Prepended Handler" and then a next alert showing "Handler declared in HTML".

But, the actual result is: Only the first alert is appearing and the second one is not.

Please tell me if you see any problem in this code.

And, how can this be done. ?

Comment: Use `this.onclick = null;` instead of `btn.attr("onclick", "return false;");`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should rearrange your click handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").each(function() {

        // your button
        var btn = $(this);

        var clickhandler = this.onclick;
        this.onclick = null;


        // new click handler
        btn.click(function() {
            alert('Prepended Handler');
        });
        btn.click(clickhandler);
    });
});

function f2() {
alert('Handler declared in HTML');
}
```

Comment: After applying it on my application, I came to know that this is not a complete solution. When I call **setTimeout(clickhandler,0);**, what will happen of the return value from that handler inside setTimeout ? I want that return value to be actually returned, but that `setTimeout` statement immediately returns.

Comment: I just updated it and tested.  The events still fire in the order you want.  If this does not work the way you want, please tell me what you are trying to return, and I'll edit it again for you.

Comment: It seems that, it may work, but actually I found an alternate way of accomplishing my task, I will try this one also, and will get back to you if it works. Just now, I am accepting the answer.

Comment: Why is `btn.attr("onclick", "return false");` needed?

Comment: @Snekse I suppose it really isn't needed.  You should probably replace that line with `this.onclick=null;` or something similar to that (I just updated my answer to do so).  I just put it there as one way of disabling the default onclick function from happening.