# How to call an event handler dynamically and get its return value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a question yesterday, I accepted the answer, but sometime later, I came to know that the solution was not complete. The question is :-

[Insert a JQuery click handler that executes before the ones already registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996830/insert-a-jquery-click-handler-that-executes-before-the-ones-already-registered)

using `setTimeout(handler,0);` returns immediately and I can not use `return setTimeout(handler,0);`. How can I run this `handler` synchronously and not allow the parent function to complete until this handler is completely executed and I get the return value out of it ?

I am in hurry, so I am asking it again, rather than editing that question again.

Comment: You need to understand how event-driven programming works. 

You cannot get the return value from any kind of event handler in the code that sets up the handler, because that calling code has continued or finished before the handler is run. The handler itself must deal with the information it returns, and display it, or put it somewhere where another asynchronous task can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `setTimeout`. If u don't use `setTimeout`, your handler reamins synchronous, and you can return all the value u want in your function.

```
<script>
   function f2() {
      alert('Handler declared in HTML')
   }

   buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  // refine this, later

   for (i = 0, max = buttons.length; i < max; i++) {
      oldonclick = buttons[i].onclick;

      buttons[i].onclick = function() {
         alert('Prepend handler');
         oldonclick();
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I have not tried it. But I got another solution, see my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answar: What about changing:

```
setTimeout(clickhandler, 0);
```

to

```
eval(clickhandler)();
```

to

```
eval(clickhandler);
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type=button]").each(function() {

            // your button
            var btn = $(this);

            // original click handler
            var clickhandler = btn.data("events").click[0];
            btn.unbind("click", clickhandler);


            // new click handler
            btn.click(function() {
                alert('Prepended Handler');
                clickhandler();
            });
        });
    });

    function f2() {
        alert('Handler declared in HTML');
    }
```

And now clickhandler is a function, right?

See: [jQuery: Unbind event handlers to bind them again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516265/jquery-unbind-event-handlers-to-bind-them-again-later)

Comment: What about eval(clickhandler); or the other example?

Comment: Also corrected my spelling error `envets` is `events` ? `inbtn.data("events")...`

Answer (score 0):

Since timeouts are asynchronous you’ll need to set the variable from within the timeout (and/or call a callback function).

```
var x = 1;

setTimeout(function() {
  x = 2;
}, 2000);
```

Here’s an example with a callback function. You need this is you want to do something with the variable as soon as it’s changed.

```
var x = 1;

function callback(x) {
  console.log(x);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  x = 2;
  callback(x);
}, 2000);
```

This will `log` `2` as soon as the timeout is executed.

Depending on what exactly it is you’re trying to do, you may not need timeouts at all, which avoids asynchronicity and a lot of trouble.