# Prepend an onclick action on a button with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a button that already has an onclick-event and an assigned function. I wish to add another function call in front of it. I can imagine it should be possible to fiddle around with the onclick attribute (`attr`), but I do not think this is best practice.

What would you consider best practice to prepend a function call on an existing onclick-event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery events: prepend a callback handler to already existing ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052349/jquery-events-prepend-a-callback-handler-to-already-existing-ones)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are not afraid to mess with the guts of jQuery:

```
// "prepend event" functionality as a jQuery plugin
$.fn.extend({
  prependEvent: function (event, handler) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var events = $(this).data("events"), 
          currentHandler;

      if (events && events[event].length > 0) {
        currentHandler = events[event][0].handler;
        events[event][0].handler = function () {
          handler.apply(this, arguments);
          currentHandler.apply(this, arguments);
        }      
      }
    });
  }
});

$("#someElement").prependEvent("click", function () {
    whatever();
});​
```

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/JtY7H/1/

Note that there must already be a `currentHandler` or the function will not do anything.

***Disclaimer:*** I consider this a hack. It depends on jQuery internals that might change in the next version of the library. It works now (I tested jQuery 1.7.2), but don't be surprised if it breaks with a future version of jQuery.

Comment: I spent last 3 hours trying to "prepend an event". @Tomalak, you rock!

Comment: `//whatever`, really :-)

Comment: I realize this answer is 8 years old, but yeah, this stopped working somewhere between 1.7.2 and 1.9.1.

Comment: @RegularJoe See disclaimer. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Haha, I know, just thought you might wanna add a note ^^. It's interesting that neither jQuery or Javascript seems to have a simple way to do this 8 years later.

Comment: @RegularJoe ...but the same approach I did back then still applies: Dig through the jQuery source code, find the location where the event handlers are stored, write a function to sneak your own event handler in there. Unless of course they made all of this unavailable through private variables, in which case it's tough luck. :)

Answer (score 6):

I've written a short [example](http://jsfiddle.net/n2eaq/) here:

```
​$("button").click(function() { // this is already existing
    if ($("span").length) {
        alert("ok");
    }
});

var clicks = $("button").data("events").click.slice();
$("button")
    .unbind("click")
    .click(function() { // this is the new one which should be prepended
        $("body").append($("<span>"));
    });
$.each(clicks, function(i, v) {
    $("button").click(v);
});
```

​

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to prepend a function call on an existing onclick event, however you can try this:

```
$('#foo').unbind('click');
$('#foo').click(function() { 
   // do new function call..
   // call original function again...
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I somehow 'get' the current click method, unbind, call my own method and then call 'whatever' was already in the click method?

Comment: As of Jquery 3.0 you should use `.off()` instead of `.unbind()`. But for my use case, i.e. removing all existing `click` event handlers so that I can replace them with my own, this was just the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You can add function on single event but I try to avoid two functions on onclick event. Instead you can
1. Add new code in existing function.
2. Add call to new function from existing function.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work in 1.9.1 through 3.1.4. See [Tomalak's awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169956/3917091) for versions before 1.9.1.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input" ).mousedown( function() {
    console.log( "mousedown" );
  });

  $("input" ).click( function() {
    console.log( "click" );
  });
    
  $.fn.extend({exposeListeners: 
      function (fn) {
        return $._data( this[0], "events") || {};
      },
    prependListener: function (types, fn) {
      var elems = this;
      $(elems).each(function() {
        var elem = this;
        var $elem = $(elem)
        $elem.on(types, fn);

        var events = $._data( $elem[0], "events")[types];

        if (events.length > 1) { // its the only event, no reason to shift
            events.unshift(events.pop());  // put last as first
        }
    
        return this;
      });
    }
  })
  
  $("#prep").click(function () {
    console.log($("input").exposeListeners());
    $("input:not(:last)").prependListener("click", function () {
      console.log('click, prepended');
    })
    $("a").prependListener("click", function () {
      console.log('click event created');
    })
    console.log($("body").exposeListeners());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="input, Will accept prepend"><br>
<input type="button" value="input, Will also accept prepend"><br>
<input type="button" value="input, Will not"><br>
<a href="#">Link with no pre-exting handlers</a><br><br>

<Button id="prep">Prepend an event</Button>
```

And here's a barebones version

```
$(function() {
  $.fn.extend({prependListener: function (types, fn) {
      var elems = this;
      $(elems).each(function() {
        var elem = this;
        var $elem = $(elem)
        $elem.on(types, fn);

        var events = $._data( $elem[0], "events")[types];

        if (events.length > 1) {
          events.unshift(events[events.length-1]);
          events.pop();
        }
    
        return this;
      });
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tested with JQuery 3.3.1 (but may work for 1.9.1 and later). See [Tomalak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169956/8740349) for versions before 1.9.1.

One of my company's projects had an issue (now fixed), where I noticed that:

- Another global-script was already handling the submit, let's call it global-handler,
- And global-handler was preventing default behavior,
- And global-handler finally did programmatically cause redirection.

Removing and/or altering said global-handler was not an option at the time.

JQuery calls listeners/handlers in order of registeration, meaning:

- Because said global-handler's logic was always required,
- But my own logic was only required on few forms,
- I needed my own-handler's logic to act as a "Middleware", in other words:

  - I needed a way to prepend my own-handler,
  - Then, only if my own-handler's validation-logic fails, prevent global-handler's logic from being called.
  - Otherwise, always call said global-handler's logic.

### Solution

> **Note** that I am using Type-script, but if required, you could cast to JavaScript (simply remove types and `declare global` section?).

First, define somewhere, maybe `plugins.ts` file, the helpers and/or JQuery plugins, like:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export type Middleware = (next: () => void) => void;

declare global {
  interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> {
    /**
     * Prepends given `middleware` to be called on enter-key and click events.
     *
     * Also, passes a trigger to "default click operation" as first argument
     * (the `next()` callback).
     *
     * WARNING: registering multiple {@link Middleware} is NOT supported yet
     * (if all target same element).
     */
    clickMiddleware(middleware: Middleware): JQuery;

    /**
     * Same as {@link JQuery.trigger} for click, but cross-platform.
     *
     * For example, JQuery intentionally does nothing for Anchor-tags
     * (which is their way to be cross-platform).
     */
    clickCompat(): JQuery;

    /**
     * Same as {@link JQuery.on}, but prepends handler.
     *
     * Additionally, may replace inline-handlers with JQuery handler
     * (because they get called before JQuery's handler).
     */
    prependEvent<TString extends string>(
      events: TString,
      handler: false
        | JQuery.TypeEventHandler<TElement, undefined, TElement, TElement, TString>
    ): this;
  }
}

export function register() {
  (<any>$.fn).clickMiddleware = function (middleware: Middleware) {
    return $(this).prependEvent('keypress click', function (event: any) {
      // May already be past middleware.
      const $element = $(this);
      if ($element.prop('isCallingDefault')) {
        $element.prop('isCallingDefault', false);
        return true;
      }

      // Executes middleware (but only for enter-key and click events).
      const logicalKey = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode || 0;
      if (logicalKey === 13 || event.type === 'click') {
        if (event.stopImmediatePropagation) event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        middleware.call(this, function () {
          $element.prop('isCallingDefault', true);
          $element.clickCompat();
        });
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    });
  };

  (<any>$.fn).clickCompat = function () {
    $(this).each(function (index, element: HTMLElement) {
      if ((<any>document).dispatchEvent) {
        let event = null;
        try {
          event = new MouseEvent('click', {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': false
          });
        } catch {
          event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
          // noinspection JSDeprecatedSymbols
          event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true,
            window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false,
            0, null);
        }
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else if ((<any>document).fireEvent) {
        element.click();
      }
    });
  };

  (<any>$.fn).prependEvent = function (eventList: string, handler: any) {
    // Using "container" param instead of "var container;".
    return $(this).each(function () {
      const $element = $(this);
      for (let event of eventList.split(' ')) {
        // Replaces inline-handlers (if possible).
        const attributeName = 'on' + event;
        const oldHandler = this[attributeName];
        if (oldHandler) {
          $element.attr(attributeName, null);
          internalPrependEvent($element, event, function () {
            oldHandler.apply(this, arguments);
          });
        }
        // Actual prepend.
        internalPrependEvent($element, event, handler);
      }
    });
  };
}

/**
 * NOTE: is already called form inside `$selection.each(...)`,
 * hence `$element.get(0)` is enough (no need to handle multiple elements).
 */
function internalPrependEvent(
  $element: JQuery<any>, eventName: string, handler: any
) {
  // Append new-listener.
  $element.on(eventName, handler);
  // Move above added new-listener to first in list.
  const container = (<any>$)._data($element.get(0), 'events')[eventName];
  container.unshift(container.pop());
}
```

### Usage

Finally, import and use above where required.

For example, OP may use it like:

```
require('./plugins').register();

$(function () {
    $('my-selector').prependEvent('click', function (event) {
        // Do something here...
    });
});
```

But I use it like:

```
require('./plugins').register();

$(function () {
    $('my-selector').clickMiddleware(function (next) {
        var valid = ... my logic here ...;
        if (valid) {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

> **Note** that my web-site fetches JQuery from CDN, and I have in my web-pack config something like:
>
> ```
> externals: {
>    jquery: 'jQuery',
> }
> ```

Answer (score -2):

If you have binded the event like this

```
$(elem).on('click', functionName);
```

you can modify that like this:

```
$(elem).on('click', function(){

 anotherFunctionNameOrWhateverYouWant();

 functionName();
});
```

Comment: That doesn't [work](http://jsfiddle.net/n2eaq/1/). `functionName` will be called two times

Comment: Yes. In the fiddle you are actually calling it twice.. I wrote modify:-) simply delete the first line in the fiddle and it will be ok..

Comment: But he's asking how he can prepend the event when the first one already exists and not how he can just add two events... there are even better methods than you've mentioned to do that.