# JQuery Live on anchor tags - Click Event - IE 8+

Tags: jquery

I've a page with different anchor tags. I want to capture the click on all the anchor events. Anchor tags can also be created in the future. So I wrote the following code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('a').live('click',function () {
            alert('click');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I found that the click is working on the anchor tags which does not have onclick attribute. But it is not working in case of some anchor tags. One such anchor tag -

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/tst_doc/somestuff.docx" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'1','XXX.OpenDocuments','')">somestuff</a>
```

So my questions is how can I make my click function to be called BEFORE inline onclick?

Any insights?

Note: Testing in IE8, IE9

Comment: Maybe `VerifyHref` return false and stop the click event

Comment: Why would you want to have 2 separate `click` events? Also, use `.on()`, as `.live()` is now deprecated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert a JQuery click handler that executes before the ones already registered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996830/insert-a-jquery-click-handler-that-executes-before-the-ones-already-registered)

Comment: Stop using live... it's depricated.

Comment: onmousedown is fired before click for sure. Inline events are fired before events binded with jquery. Non delegated events are fired before delegated ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot achieve this. If you have several handlers for the same event type assigned to the same element, then the order of execution of handlers is not determined:

> W3C model does not state which event handler is fired first

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

P.S. Consider using .on() instead of .live(), which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```